# Copy in insert mode with mouse

Tags: clipboard, vsvim

I'm using vsvim, sometimes I highlight code in insert mode with my mouse and want to copy or cut it out. But I don't know-how. Instead, I have to change back to normal mode, highlight it again then cut it. I tried to Ctrl+O but it would get rid of the highlight. Does anyone know how to solve this?
[highlighted text in insert mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4scm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this extension, but when running vim natively, if you highlight stuff in insert mode, you can right-click and click on copy. Not sure whether this works in Visual Studio. However, reading the [docs](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vscodevim-settings) in GitHub I see there is a `vim.handleKeys` setting, that you can set in `settings.json` and you could specify `C-c` and `C-v` to be false in order to support Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v natively. The doc provides this example:

```
"vim.handleKeys": { "<C-f>": false }
```

which in your case would look like this:

```
"vim.handleKeys": { 
    "<C-c>": false, 
    "<C-d>": false 
}
```